# Extracting Sprites from Spritesheets in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, sprite, extract

Recently I've been experimenting with spritesheets, particularly in AS3. I've managed to extract standard sprites and develop functional animations through sheets with equal sized squares. A lot of spritesheets on the internet aren't properly organized with equal sized squares though. Is there a way to manipulate pixels to obtain the location and dimensions of sprites from these sheets dynamically? Or must I modify the spritesheet itself to a 'square format'?. I want to avoid hard-coding as much as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of spritesheets is often to reduce the overhead of data.  Loading one image is much faster than loading hundreds of images.  Because you can have variable sized images, most spritesheets generated will also come with a secondary file that defines where in the spritesheet you can find each image.  Then, it's just a matter of referencing the x, y, width, and height values for that image.

[TexturePacker](https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker) will generate these, as I imagine most other apps do.

Answer (score 0):

Typically if you have non-regular sized and/or spaced sprites, you'd also have an accompanying data file (XML or JSON probably) that defines the locations and sizes of the different sprites.